# Why do I need the new Context API? The value is already imported

Tags: reactjs

The new Context API require the consumer to import the context from where it's created.

So why the consumer needs to define `contextType`? I can just use the imported value.

```
import ThemeContext from './context/theme';

class Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.context}</div>
    );
  }
}

Consumer.contextType = ThemeContext; // why?
```

If I have a component `ComponentA` in package `PackageA`, and it requires a context. How to define the context for it?

```
// PackageA/ComponentA.js, managed by npm/yarn
import PackageContext from './context';

class ComponentA {}

ComponentA.contextType = PackageContext;

// ===========================================

// src/App.js
import ComponentA from 'PackageA/ComponentA';

const MyContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value="app context">
      <ComponentA />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The only way I came up is like this. But I just can't like it.

```
// src/ComponentA.js
import ComponentA from 'PackageA/ComponentA';

ComponentA.contextType = MyContext;

export default ComponentA;

// And just import this component instead of the one in `PackageA`,
// although we can still use it because it's modified.
```

Answer (score 1):

[`contextType` static property](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype) is supposed to be used with class components together with `context` instance property and serve as an alternative to `ThemeContext.Consumer`. In case of functional component it affects nothing, `Consumer.contextType` isn't needed.

A counterpart to `contextType` in functional component is [`useContext` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext), since React 16.8:

```
function Consumer() {
  const theme = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <div>{theme}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But the context is still imported, it is not supposed to be modified. Hooks api do not make this better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How is it 'modified'? That you import a context and you use it are two different things. You cannot get context value directly from `ThemeContext` object, at least officially. You need to provide it to a component in some way - `ThemeContext.Consumer`, OR `contextType`, OR `useContext`.

Comment: Please take a look in the second code block. I imported the context for ComponentA, and then I can’t use context with other value in App.js.

Comment: In case you need context value in App component, you can it exactly like the answer suggests, with useContext. I'm not totally sure what the code you posted should do. *The only way I came up is like this.* - how is it supposed to work? Are you trying to replace `context `used in `ComponentA`? What is `ComponentA` exactly?The question seems to be very specific to the code you're using. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem you have. No-op abstractions don't give a good idea about your case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I’ll make a more detailed example.

Comment: The question doesn't show `ComponentA` and why contextType is needed there at all. Is PackageA/ComponentA.js third-party component? Please, provide original component.

Comment: Yes, it's a package install by `npm`. it can be customized using context API.

Comment: What package exactly? I'm positive it shouldn't be customized the way it did. I don't understand the purpose of `ComponentA.contextType = PackageContext`. Did this even work? Please, provide MCVE, the question cannot be answered without it.